# What is the correct grammatical formation of this paragraph?

Tags: punctuation, syntactic-analysis

I have seen this particular *meme* trending on a lot of social media platforms of late.
I'm wondering what the grammatically correct formation of the *meme* (phrase) is?

The *meme* in questions reads as follows:

> 'I would rather cuddle then have sex. 
>   If you're good with grammar, you'll get it.'

It's clear to me the composers attempting witty wordplay with the *meme* (phrase) itself, by using 'then', where 'than' in turn would change the phrases intended meaning.

I'm curious as to whether there should be a comma between *cuddle then*? 
For example, as I understand it should read as follows:

> 'I would rather cuddle, then have sex. If you're good with grammar, you'll get it.'

Comment: Yes, the comma would make it read correctly - but it would mess up the joke.

Comment: I think the comma is optional as it is not ambiguous.

Comment: Regarding the original author, I don't know if the "it" there is meant to be both euphemistic and in addition to the previous comment. But otherwise grammar smart-arses who don't know the difference between vocabulary and grammar deserve a punch in the asterisk ...

Comment: The comma makes it too obvious.  As @Oldbag says, it would mess up the joke.

Comment: @Araucaria it appears to be more about semantics than vocabulary (which I would deem as orthography in spelling mistakes/intentional choices, as it is here). It's a bad (horribly conceived) joke, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

The comma can absolutely be used there.

> I would rather cuddle **than** have sex.

However, in the above version, the comma can't be used before *than* because the sentence is a comparison, and a comma would break it up.

> I would rather cuddle, **then** have sex.

In this version, the comma can be used, but the meme doesn't use it because it is a play on words and is therefore supposed to reflect the *than* version.